# {Content.EditUrl} token does not work for content that hasn't been published

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I am using Orchard 1.9.2 and have a workflow setup to send an email out with the {Content.EditUrl} token in it. It works fine as long as the content has been published at least once, but if it has only been saved as a draft and never published then it just shows up blank in the email when the workflow is triggered.

Is this is a bug?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Try to debug in Modules/Orchard.Tokens/Providers/ContentTokens.cs in the `EditUrl` method

Comment: The tokens use the GetItemMedata from the contentManager which I never had any issues with, regardless of the publishing-state.
But I'd debug too and look into the context and check if your content is actually in there.

Do you use custom workflow steps? If so, could you post your workflow setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using just a regular Get, `_contentManager.Get(id)`, when I should have been using `_contentManager.GetLatest(id)` when triggering the event.